Failed to Install postgresql-client-16 into docker container
I have a Dockerfile that starts like this
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends postgresql-client

This will install the PostgreSQL client as expected, but in the wrong version.
pg_dump: pg_dump: error: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_dump: pg_dump: detail: server version: 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1); pg_dump version: 15.6 (Debian 15.6-0+deb12u1)

Attempting to specify the version postgresql-client-16 directly results in
Unable to locate package postgresql-client-16

Directly adding the source results in some new error messages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget gnupg2
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/postgresql.gpg
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/postgresql.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bullseye-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends postgresql-client-16

postgresql-client-16 : Depends: libpq5 (>= 16.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable

Trying to install the libs results in errors as well.
What am I doing wrong here and how can I install the postgres-client tools in the Docker image?

If you use the Alpine 3.19 base image then you'll get a version of the PostgreSQL client which works with servers with major version 16.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine as base

RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-client

CMD pg_dump --version

The resulting pg_dump version is
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 16.2


I tried the above but got the following error:  Error DT1001 failed to solve: dockerfile parse error on line 8: unknown instruction: as (did you mean arg?)

Argh! No, that was just me being a twit. Simple copy-paste failure. Have updated my answer.
